# Math question partial derivatives?

Tags: partial-derivative

I have to find ∂z/∂x and dz/dx if z=ln(e^x+e^y) ,y=x^3
Awesome.Now, I write ∂z/∂x=(∂z/∂y)*(∂y/∂x) .I find ∂z/∂y=e^y/(e^x+e^y) ..but how do I find ∂y/∂x?  what is its value?

Comment: Is this the whole question? And can you edit your first line, you ask the same twice?

Comment: Go to the FAQ section to read about how to use LaTeX in this site to write mathematics properly

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you didn't show the entire question yet, I think you want to know this:

The derivative of $z$ with respect to $x$:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{e^x}{e^x+e^y}$$

The derivative of $z$ with respect to $y$:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{e^y}{e^x+e^y}$$

The derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$:
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=3x^2$$

Your approach won't work on different formulas. As you can see when you multiply the partial derivatives you suggested.

Comment: So ,I don't do the multiplication? I just find ∂z/∂x straight away?

Comment: That's really the easiest way, yes :)